# How to get MethodInfo for basic methods, not properties and events, via reflection?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I'm performing some reflective interrogation of an object. The code lists constructor(s), properties, and methods. `GetMethods( )` returns property accessor/mutator methods and event add/remove methods.

How can I get just the basic method definitions?

**Update**

```
.IsSpecialName
```

is the operative property. Thanks, @Hans.

Comment: Can't you get it from parameter types and return type

Comment: See my answer on the question I linked as duplicate.

Comment: You will cast a wide net with GetMethods().  Filter out the special ones by ignoring those whose IsSpecialName property is true.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: I searched a page of possible dupes...arrgg!

Answer (score 16):

The following answer from this post [Filtering out auto-generated methods getter/setter/add/remove/.etc) returned by Type.GetMethods()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3661539/filtering-out-auto-generated-methods-getter-setter-add-remove-etc-returned-by) should work

```
typeof(MyType)
.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
.Where(m => !m.IsSpecialName)
```