# How get all public static members without getters and setters via reflection?

Tags: c#, linq, reflection, .net-3.5

My code is

```
    var memberList = from member in type.GetMembers(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
        .Where(m => !(m.Name.Contains("get_") || m.Name.Contains("set_") ||
                    m.Name.Contains("add_") || m.Name.Contains("remove_")) )
        select member;
```

What a more elegant way?

UPD: And without add_/remove_ members of event handlers

Comment: Do you really want the `add`/`remove` members of event handlers? Are you *actually* just trying to get methods, rather than all members?

Comment: You could filter using the negation of [`MethodBase.IsSpecialName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.isspecialname.aspx).  This may or may not filter away too much.  What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What do you meant by "members"?  Methods?  Fields? Everything?

Comment: Methods, fields, properties and events

Comment: possible duplicate of [Filtering out auto-generated methods (getter/setter/add/remove/.etc) returned by Type.GetMethods()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3661539/filtering-out-auto-generated-methods-getter-setter-add-remove-etc-returned-by)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make a query of the defined accessors and then exclude those:

```
var propertyAccessors = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
                            .SelectMany(p => p.GetAccessors())
                            .Cast<MemberInfo>();

var eventAccessors = type.GetEvents(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
                         .SelectMany(e => new[] {
                             e.GetAddMethod(true),
                             e.GetRemoveMethod(true)
                         })
                         .Cast<MemberInfo>();

var accessors = propertyAccessors.Concat(eventAccessors);

var memberList = type.GetMembers(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
                     .Except(accessors);
```

You might be able to get away with filtering out just those methods that don't have special names (as defined by [`MethodBase.IsSpecialName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.isspecialname.aspx).

```
var memberList = type.GetMembers(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
                     .Where(m => {
                         var method = m as MethodBase;
                         return method == null || !method.IsSpecialName;
                     });
```

Comment: @user2217261 Are you not using .NET 4.5?  I've modified the example to be compatible with .NET 4.0 and earlier.

Comment: How would you then go about putting the memberList `var` into an actual MemberInfo array or list?

Comment: @Freerey `memberList.ToList()`