# how to prevent getmethods from retrieve a specific method

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a static class with private functions, I want to get all functions except one. I tried using Ignorecase but i get an overload exception... I do it exactly like many examples online but I get an error and I dont know why...am I missing something?

//Example

```
static MethodInfo[] allFuncs ;
static Type myType = typeof(myClass);        
allFuncs = myType.GetMethods("innerFunction", 
                BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
```

Comment: How are you filtering out the overload you don't want?

Comment: using the bindingflags - I want private and static without method: innerFunction

Comment: You want all `private` and `static` methods except for `innerFunction`?

Comment: Question already asked 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3661539/filtering-out-auto-generated-methods-getter-setter-add-remove-etc-returned-by

Answer (score 1):

If you want all methods except one with a particular name, you can use [`Enumerable.Where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb549418(v=vs.100).aspx) to filter:

```
allFuncs = typeof(MyClass).GetMethods(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static)
                          .Where(method => !method.Name.Equals(
                                    "innerFunction", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

Comment: i'll try it, but why doesn't  my option work ? what is the problem?

Comment: @Damkulul The problem is you're not using `Type.GetMethod` correctly (note your answer says you're using `GetMethods`, although there's no overload of it accepting a `string`). The overload that you're using is trying to find the specific method named `innerFunction`, which is exactly the opposite of what you want.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3661539/filtering-out-auto-generated-methods-getter-setter-add-remove-etc-returned-by

Comment: @Damkulul I removed that. It is part of LINQPad.