# Identify whether a MethodInfo instance is a property accessor

Tags: c#, reflection

I am writing a decorating proxy using [Castle DynamicProxy](http://www.castleproject.org/dynamicproxy/index.html). I need the proxy's interceptor to intercept only property writes (not reads) so I am checking the name of the method thusly:

```
public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
{
    if (invocation.Method.Name.StartsWith("set_")
    {
        // ...
    }

    invocation.Proceed();
}
```

Now this works fine but I don't like the fact my proxy has intimate knowledge of how properties are implemented: I'd like to replace the method name check with something akin to:

```
if (invocation.Method.IsPropertySetAccessor)
```

Unfortunately my Google-fu has failed me. Any ideas?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could check whether a property exists for which this method is the setter (untested):

```
bool isSetAccessor = invocation.Method.DeclaringType.GetProperties() 
        .Any(prop => prop.GetSetMethod() == invocation.Method)
```

(Inspiration taken from [Marc's answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520138/finding-the-hosting-propertyinfo-from-the-methodinfo-of-getter-setter/520155#520155).)

Comment: Looks very inneficient

Comment: @thepirat000: Well, if `GetSetMethod` is O(1), this would be O(n). That's probably not optimal (and I'll definitely upvote any alternative answer which is equally readable and yields better performance), but I'm sure you know the saying about premature optimization being the root of all evil...

Comment: I would suggest you to check if the method has "get_" prefix (casesensitive) and remove it from the method collection (still O(n) complexity - which is rather cheap). In addition you can add `Dictionary<Type, MethodInfo>` instance to hold already checked types which first gives you the complexity of O(n) but afterwards O(1)

Answer (score 7):

There isn't any voodoo of which I'm aware. You *could*, perhaps, strip the `set_`, look for a property with that name, and compare the `MethodInfo` instance (`invocation.Method`) to the property accessor (`GetSetMethod()`) - however, I can't honestly say (without checking) whether you will get the same `MethodInfo` instance (even if it *is* the same method).

```
if(method.IsSpecialName && method.Name.StartsWith("set_"))
{
    var prop = typeof (Foo).GetProperty(method.Name.Substring(4),
           BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
    var accessor = prop.GetSetMethod();
    bool isSame = accessor == method;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what kind of type the invocation.Method is, but if you can get the PropertyInfo you can use the [IsSpecialName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.isspecialname.aspx). Unfortunately this tells not only if the property is a set_ or _get but also if it is an overloaded operator.

Answer (score -1):

First, you can examine the `MemberType` property of `MethodInfo` class to see if it's a `Property`.

Now, you should try to guess if it's a get or a set. If you don't want to analyse the name (someone might name a method "set_Something"), then you can check the arguments.

- If the property accessor accepts one parameter and returns `void`,
  **it is a set**
- If the property accessor returns one value and doesn't pick parameters, **it is a get**

You may be interested only in the first check

Comment: Just asking out of curiosity. What about the this[] operator? I think it allows one parameter.

Comment: The `MemberType` of a property accessor method is `MemberTypes.Method` not `MemberTypes.Property`. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @dowhilefor: good point!!! Can you see in Reflector/ILDASM what is the result and tell us? I don't have both Reflector and an assembly with a this accessor at hand, but mscorlib.dll should be full of them

Answer (score -1):

from your [MethodInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.aspx) object get the [MemberType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.membertype.aspx) property which should say this is a [Property type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.membertypes.aspx) so you should be able to cast it to [PropertyInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.aspx) instead. that object exposes the property [CanWrite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.canwrite.aspx) which tells if this is a setter.

Comment: Hmm, the documentation seems to imply that the `MemberType` will be `MemberTypes.Method` for `MethodInfo` objects.

Comment: hmm, you're right, I have overlooked this and expected it to be MemberTypes.Property for MethodInfo objects created for properties, maybe it is I'm not sure anymore now

Comment: I've just run a test: the `MemberType` of a property accessor method is `MemberTypes.Method` not `MemberTypes.Property` so this does not fly. Thanks anyhow.

Answer (score -4):

I think you may try using extension methods:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx

Comment: Thanks, but this is how my current solution works. I am looking for one that does not require my application to know about C# compiler implementation details.

Comment: He could use an extension method to add an `IsPropertySetAccessor` method to the `MethodInfo` type, but the problem he has is what would go in that method that's better than what he has now. **"I don't like the fact my proxy has intimate knowledge of how properties are implemented"**

Comment: This answer is pretty unhelpful - the question seems to be pointing more at the "what would go *inside* a method to determine this"