# System.Reflection - How can I tell if a MethodInfo object is a Method or a Property accessor?

Tags: c#, reflection

I have two similar (not identical) dlls, one of them being actually a part of the other. I am trying to see if there is still compatibility (that is, if the smaller one is still fully included in the larger).

I am doing this by iterating through all the type in the smaller dll and checking if each **method** in them also exists (name and parameter list) in the larger dll.

The problem is that Assembly.GetMethods() returns both methods and **property getters/setters**, which I guess, yeah, are a kind of method, but this is bad for me in this circumstance.

So, my question is, how can I tell if a MethodInfo object stores a property or a *real* method?

Comment: Looks like a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7819489/identify-whether-a-methodinfo-instance-is-a-property-accessor ?

Comment: @AakashM: It seems so indeed, unfortunately I did not find that before and was in a bit of a hurry, thanks for pointing that out. Is there anything I have to do in cases like this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Property accessors are marked as `specialname` by the compiler. You can check this with [`MethodBase.IsSpecialName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.isspecialname.aspx), which you can check on your `MethodInfo` object. This property is also true for other special methods, such as operator overloads.

Another possibility to exclude property getters and setters would be this query:

```
from m in typeof(SomeType).GetMethods()
where !typeof(SomeType).GetProperties().Any(p => p.GetGetMethod() == m || p.GetSetMethod() == m)
select m;
```

Comment: Yes, that detects property accessors, but property accessors aren't the only methods that are marked as SpecialName, so it will give false positives.

Comment: +1 for working out your second suggestion, although I'd consider calling `GetGetMethod(nonPublic: true)` and similarly for the setter and the `GetMethods`/`GetProperties` calls themselves.

Comment: Your first solution works well enough for me, as I need only the "pure" methods, so I have to exclude everything else. I thank you very much indeed, sir! :D

Answer (score 2):

A property accessor *is* a method. A property is nothing more than syntactic shorthand for a get/set accessor.

```
class A
{
    public int P { get { return 0; } }
}
```

could have been written, if C# were defined differently, as

```
class A
{
    public int get_P() { return 0; }
    public int P { get: get_P }
}
```

If you understand that, you may see that a `MethodInfo` cannot tell you the answer you're looking for. Instead, you have to take the opposite path: see if there are any *properties* (and perhaps events too) that use that *method* as an accessor. You could use `Type.GetProperties()` and a simple `foreach` loop.

Comment: Yep, just got that. Thanks for clearing that up. I have started with Reflection yesterday and this is due today, so was in a hurry. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't try, but this should help :

```
var isMethod = (yourMethodInfo.MemberType & MemberTypes.Method) == MemberTypes.Method;
```

More on this : [MemberTypes enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.membertypes.aspx) and [MethodInfo.MemberType property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.membertype.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I have tried several things with MemberTypes, and it seems that all of them are seen as methodInfo.MemberType == MemberTypes.Method.  I guess that's cause they are implicit properties...

Answer (score -1):

Try the following,

```
methodInfo.IsDefined(typeof(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute), false);
methodinfo.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property
```

Comment: @RajeshSubramanian Why would either of your suggestions help? I'm not saying you're just randomly guessing, I'm saying I don't understand why you're suggesting them.