# Using attribute of inherited property from an interface

Tags: c#, inheritance, custom-attributes

I've been trying to use an attribute of a property that has been declared in an interface.

Assume:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, Inherited=true)]
class My1Attribute : Attribute
{
    public int x { get; set; }
}

interface ITest
{
    [My1]
    int y { get; set; }
}

class Child : ITest
{
    public Child() { }

    public int y { get; set; }
}
```

Now, from what I read, GetCustomAttribute() with inheritance=true should return the inherited attribute, but it looks it doesn't work.

```
Attribute my = typeof(Child).GetProperty("y").GetCustomAttribute(typeof(My1Attribute), true); // my == null
```

Why doesn't it work? and how can I get the attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Child` does not have any custom attributes, `ITest` has them, so you will have to call `GetCustomAttributes` on the members of `ITest`.

There is a difference between inheritance and implementation. Inheritance would be fine if `Child` was derived from some base class that had a `y` property decorated with `My1Attribute`.

In your case, `Child` *implements* `ITest` and `ITest` is a different type, outside of the inheritance hierarchy.

```
void Main()
{
    var my1Attribute = typeof(ITest).GetProperty("y").GetCustomAttribute(typeof(My1Attribute)) as My1Attribute;
    Console.WriteLine(my1Attribute.x); // Outputs: 0
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, Inherited = true)]
class My1Attribute : Attribute
{
    public int x { get; set; }
}

interface ITest
{
    [My1]
    int y { get; set; }
}

class Child : ITest
{
    public Child() { }

    public int y { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a sketch, not a detailed answer. It should give an idea of how you could find the attribute, starting from `Child`.

You can use `typeof(Child).GetInterfaces()` to get an array from which you can see that `Child` implements `ITest`. Suppose `t` is the `typeof(ITest)` you got out of the array, then:

```
typeof(Child).GetInterfaceMap(t)
```

will give you a structure ("map") to see what the property getter (`get` accessor) `get_y` from `Child` (in `.TargetMethods`) corresponds to in the interface (`.InterfaceMethods`). The answer is another `get_y` of course. So what you have is the `MethodInfo` of the `get` accessor of the `y` property in `ITest`. To find the property itself, see e.g. [this answer to *Finding the hosting PropertyInfo from the MethodInfo of getter/setter*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/520155/1336654). Once you have the property info, inspect its custom attributes to find the `My1Attribute` and its value of `x`.