# How to exclude some methods in Fody when using MethodBoundaryAspect

Tags: c#, fody

I am using Fody to log every method "OnExit". It looks like this:

```
[CustomLog(AttributeTargetMemberAttributes = MulticastAttributes.Public)]
public class Driver
{

    public static void Close()
    public static void Quit()
    public static void DeleteCookies()
    public static void Navigate(string url)

}
```

The class for the CustomLog looks like this:

```
public sealed class CustomLogAttribute : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
```

I want to exclude the method **DeleteCookies** from logging in the **Driver** class. Eventually, I want to have the decision to exclude any other method. I worked before with PostSharp and they have this code:

```
[CustomLog(AttributeExclude=true)]
```

But I have not been able to find something similar in Fody. I appreciate any help.

Update:
I was able to find a solution thanks to Kirk Woll. Now I am able to read the attributes from methods but not properties.

```
public class DoNotLog : Attribute
{
    public DoNotLog()
    {

    }
}
```

```
[DoNotLog]
public static IWebDriver Current {get;}
```

```
public override void OnExit(MethodExecutionArgs args)
{
    // Avoid logging the methods marked as [DoNotLog]
    IEnumerable<CustomAttributeData> attributes = args.Method.CustomAttributes;
    var result = args.Method.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(DoNotLog));
            
}
```

Comment: I'm confused as your `OnMethodBoundaryAspect` is apparently a PostSharp class, which you said you weren't using.  Did you roll your own version?

Comment: @KirkWoll , Fody implements the same class name.

Comment: If that's true, the class name doesn't appear in their [repository](https://github.com/Fody/Fody/search?q=OnMethodBoundaryAspect).

Comment: My bad, this is part of Fody but I am using the weaver [MethodBoundaryAspect.Fody](https://github.com/vescon/MethodBoundaryAspect.Fody)

Comment: It looks like the `OnEnter` and other methods you override in `CustomLog` provides a `MethodExecutionArgs` class which contains a property `Method` that you can use to discriminate whether or not to exclude the logging.  You could extend that by creating your own attribute that you can decorate on methods and interrorage that `Method` property for the presence of tha attribute.

Comment: You are right @KirkWoll. That solves my problem! Thank you

Comment: Glad I could help.  Feel free to self-answer your question.

Comment: One more challenge ... I am able to read the attribute from methods, but not from the Properties. Any idea? Example code:
`[DoNotLog]
 public static IWebElement Current`

This code does not recognize the attributes of the properties but it works for methods:
`IEnumerable<CustomAttributeData> attributes = args.Method.CustomAttributes;
 var result = args.Method.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(DoNotLog));`

Comment: The problem there is that the `get;` and `set;` in properties are actual methods and you're (understandably) applying the attribute to the enclosing `PropertyInfo`.  You have two options: apply the attribute directly to the setter (such as `IWebElement Current { get; [DoNotLog] set; }` or figure out how to map the get/set methods back to the `PropertyInfo` yourself.  The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/520155/189950) helped me out in a similar situation.

Comment: That worked like a charm. Thank you @KirkWoll . Adding the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Like @KirkWoll suggested, the solution is first to use `MethodExecutionArgs` to filter based on the property that I should create.

```
public override void OnExit(MethodExecutionArgs args)
{
    // Avoid logging the methods marked as [DoNotLog]
    IEnumerable<CustomAttributeData> attributes = args.Method.CustomAttributes;
    var result = args.Method.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(DoNotLog));            
}
```

And for the properties, the attribute should be added to the **GET** or **SET** and not on the Property